# asp mvc 3 multiselect listbox. map each selected option to collection element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For example we have a view model with fields:

```
    public List<string> SelectedTestItems { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AllTestItems { get; set; }
```

and view with:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.SelectedTestItems, Model.AllTestItems)
```

And now when i open the view, select 3 items in listbox and submit the form(via jquery $.post and $.serialize ), for some reason in controller I get view model with one item in SelectedTestItems collection, and this item is comma separated values that i selected in listbox (SelectedTestItems[0] = "1,2,3")

is it possible to map listbox to something like this:

SelectedTestItems[0] = "1",
SelectedTestItems[1] = "2",
SelectedTestItems[2] = "3" ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tested here and I received each value separated. Can you show all your code? Maybe we can see what is wrong.

Comment: ahh. now i see that the problem is in serializeAnything plugin.